# How to make """this text""" which is in Python, in Common Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp

Python has:

```
"""
line1
line2
line3
"""
```

How can I do this in Common Lisp?

Comment: The answer provided by @coredump was correct, please consider accepting the answer. These are small things but the help the community :)

Answer (score 6):

This is just a regular string:

```
"
line1
line2
line3
"
```

You need to escape internal double quotes characters, though.

If you don't want to escape quotes, then you have to change the readtable. In fact, you could easily have the behavior you want (and more) by using the [cl-interpol](http://weitz.de/cl-interpol/) library, which defines a custom syntax for strings, notably different kind of *outer delimiters*.

```
CL-USER> (ql:quickload :cl-interpol)
...
CL-USER> (interpol:enable-interpol-syntax)
; No value
CL-USER> #?(some string)
"some string"
CL-USER> #?(some string with a "string" inside)
"some string with a \"string\" inside"
CL-USER> #?(some string with (nested (parentheses)))
"some string with (nested (parentheses))"
```

Comment: @1.618 Edited the answer